# R 3.1.0, table(x,y) function on Window 8.1, situation with the tabulation

Tags: r

I'm looking a situation when I try to tabulate result with the function table(x,y), by example, creating a table with the next code:

```
set.seed(150)
rr01<-rep(sample(1:100,100),10)
rcut<-cut(rr01,quantile(rr01))
rr<-data.frame(sample=rr01,cut=rcut)
rrtable<-table(rr$cut,rr$sample)
```

The first value of this tabulated table (1,1) is zero, this happen with all kind of tables, always the result of the first value is zero, although this value should count the times the first value appear in the first group, in this case **10**

How can I fix it?

Comment: You may want to look at `table(rr$cut,rr$sample,useNA="ifany")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `cut` include the left endpoint with the `include.lowest` option:

```
set.seed(150)
rr01<-rep(sample(1:100,100),10)
rcut<-cut(rr01,quantile(rr01), include.lowest=TRUE)
rr<-data.frame(sample=rr01,cut=rcut)
rrtable<-table(rr$cut,rr$sample)
rrtable
#                1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
#   [1,25.8]    10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
#   (25.8,50.5]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#   (50.5,75.2]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#   (75.2,100]   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#   ...
```